# Space gap in the middle?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap, what I need to do when I need a gap in the middle.

Content container is `col-md-6` and image container is `col-md-5`

For example:

[image]

Should it be something like this:

```
    <div class="info-container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          <p>Quisque ut nulla enim. Nullam placerat metus risus, quis scelerisque felis pretium tristique. Vivamus mi tellus, lacinia at rutrum quis</p>
        </div> 
        <div  class="col-md-5">           
            <img src="img/image.jpg" alt ="">  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @DavidG Empty space in the middle, after `col-md-6` as you can see in the image.

Comment: @DavidG I have tested it and it did not give a space gap in the middle. I need a gap.

Comment: @DavidG Yes I need a gap

Comment: class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include a gap you need to offst the column with `col-md-offset-1` like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="info-container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>Quisque ut nulla enim. Nullam placerat metus risus, quis scelerisque felis pretium tristique. Vivamus mi tellus, lacinia at rutrum quis</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```